# Symfony Routes without app/config/routing.yaml

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

The tutorials I've read for Symfony 2 instructs users to enter their routing information in

```
app/config/routing.yml
```

If users want to have routing information in their own bundles, they're instructed to add a `routing.yml` file to their Bundle, and then point to their file from `app/config/routing.yml` with something like

```
my_route_stuff:
    resource: "@CustomstuffBundle/resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Is there any way to skip the "add this extra configuration to the `app/config/routing.yml` file? I'm looking for the ability to hand off a bundle to someone else, and have them be able to deploy it into their Symfony application without needing to edit their own `app/config/routing.yml`.

If this isn't possible, bonus point if anyone can explain why (i.e: the general philosophy behind) routing information is part of the `AppKernel` instead of the individual Bundles.  I'm still a little unclear on the differences between `routing.yml` files and the normal Symfony `config.yml` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there any way to skip the "add this extra configuration to the app/config/routing.yml file?**

No, this is the way [SonataAdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/getting_started.html), [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-6-import-fosuserbundle-routing-files) and a bunch of others handle it.

**Why?**

Routing belongs to the application, not each and every bundle. If every bundle started including their own routing files and Symfony2 autoloaded them, you would quickly have a mess of routes you may or may not want to enable in your application.

What if SonataAdminBundle wanted you to use `/admin`, but you already had a route there and wanted Sonata to use `/sonata/admin` instead? You'd need a file to override those routes and then you're back to square one!

Additionally, although caching mitigates this part, looking up files is expensive and would significantly slow down the development environment. This is why translation files are read from cache even in dev mode and you must clear the cache when you add a new translation resource. See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#message-catalogues

Finally, leaving the routing out of config.yml is simply a matter of organization. Routing and configuration are two different things and don't belong in the same file.

The general idea is that every file is a *thing* and should only do that *thing*.

Comment: Perfect, just the answer I was looking for. (although, of course, the problem is all things are made up of other things, and what's a single thing to one developer could be two different things to another)

Comment: i don't agree 100% here ... frameworkbundle auto-registers internal routes ( _internal, _profiler )aswell, as does assetic ... you could still have a bundle auto-register routes and make them configurable with configuration, then let other bundles register subroutes/urls using container tags ... auto-generated routes can come in handy in some cases

Comment: Aren't these routes generated in routing.yml as a part of the installation process? They're more an exception rather than the rule. Of course you could have configurable routes, but as I mentioned, at that point you're back to square one and might as well have it all in one place, routing.yml